# What is the difference between github packages and other (maven) repositories

Tags: maven, github

Recently, github launched a new [service](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-packages-with-github-packages) called 'Github packages'. In terms of the maven ecosystem, how would you describe/define the Github package service? How does Github package service communicate with the maven central repository?
When would it make sense to switch to github packages, i.e. are there any major considerations one would make to switch to github packages, or to stick with a repository manager such as [Sonatype Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/product-nexus-repository)?